# Using another domain, whilst masking the current domains filepath?

Tags: redirect, path, dns, mask

First and foremost I'd like to apologize for posting this question - there  are plenty of answers to it from other users asking on Stackeroverflow, but I have managed to confuse myself terribly in reading them all.

I have setup a MyBB forum on my hosting space, under www.domainone.com/path/theforum.php

It would be much easier for me to simply point the clients domain at the forum instead of shifting everything over to another webhost.

Is there any way of doing this so it just shows www.clientsdomain.com as the fourm, instead of www.clientsdomain.com/path/theforum.php (the path it currently has on my webserver/domain?

I'm sure it's something simple, but I'm just a little boggled by all the answers of DNS and masking etc. Guidance from someone who knows this kind of stuff would be much appreciated, thank-you very much.

Comment: http://community.mybb.com/thread-98848-post-721803.html#pid721803

Comment: Thank-you very much, I didn't think to do a Google search in relation to MyBB. That should do the trick, cheers.